# Itextsharp : OnEndPage event not called

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am trying to add header in existing PDF file with help of `PDFPageEventHelper`. I am getting error `document has no pages` in some files. The code works perfectly for other files. While debugging I found that for some files `OnEndPage` method is not called which may cause to throw exception 'document has no pages'

Any idea why this method or event (OnEndPage) is not called ?

Comment: *"I found that for some files `OnEndPage` method is not called which may cause to throw exception 'document has no pages'"* - No, the fact that `OnEndPage` is not called is not the *cause* of the exception but instead an *effect* like the exception... an *effect* of the fact that you try to close the writer without adding any content to it. This in turn usually happens if some other exception occurs early inside a `using (PdfWriter ...)` or `using (Document ...)` block. In such a case the exception ends the `using` block causing the writer to be closed without content, triggering the error.

Comment: That being said, you're using the wrong classes: *to add header in existing PDF file* one does not use a writer but instead a stamper.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your PDF files do not contain any page information. PDF renders content into bounding boxes. All you do is to define a box and render stuff into it. Therefore you do not need any page information.

Out there - in da real world - exists a lot of crazy pages. Some declare a box so that (0,0) is in the middle of the box. Perfect for drawing functions, but some libraries fail, because they think only in pages starting with left/top corner as (0,0). And such boxes can be transformed multiple times inside a document.

Many PDF documents contain a lot of parts which break PDF rules. There are some tools on the markets, which will validate your files against the PDF references. A few try to fix them. A cheap workaround may be to read the PDF into libre office and save it again as PDF. This will fix only a small set of errors, but yours may be among them.

You have to read the failing documents in a text editor to find the reason. But it is a pain in the a*

Comment: thanks for help. I have figured out that this error is occurring when existing pdf file has page with 'landscape' orientation and below is the code causing error. cb.Add(page). cb=PdfContentByte.

Comment: Check first, if the page is really in landscape. you can define the box of the page in portrait and set the landscape metadata. Get the source from iText and switch on all exceptions.